# Why does it give me a range error when i only tried to print the value only when its not null?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

```
List nums = [1, 2, 3];
print(nums[10] ?? nums[0]);
```

Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 10

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator on `List` are not nullable. So it does not return `null` if you are asking for an element not in the `List`. Instead, it documents a requirement that the given index must be in the `List`:

> The index must be a valid index of this list, which means that index must be non-negative and less than length.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List/operator_get.html

This is different from the `[]` operator on `Map` which does return `null` in case the asked element does not exist in the `Map`.

A reason for this design choice would be that it would get really annoying if we should always handle potential null values when asking for elements in lists. Especially since we often do iterate the list where we take the length into account.

Compared to `Map` where we are more likely to use it as some form of cache.